What is this diode's purpose in an LR7843 MOSFET control module?
I would like to know the purpose of a diode connected to the optoisolator and gate resistor of this Chinese MOSFET module.
Is it for reverse polarity protection?
What kind of diode could it be?
I've rarely seen a diode in an SMD glass package.
Schematic:
(image from: protosupplies.com - LR7843 MOSFET CONTROL MODULE):

Module photo (image from: protosupplies.com - LR7843 MOSFET CONTROL MODULE):


Is a parts list available for the MOSFET module? If so, that would help to determine the type of the diode.

I have some difficulty with that circuit. If it is powered at 6v there is less than 3v at the mosfet gate. It will not be fully conducting. I guess the relatively strong gate pull down resistor is to support the claimed PWM function.


Also, what kind of diode could it be?

The module photo in the question contains a label of HW-532.
Searching found EasyEDA HW-532. The Open in Editor button displays the following schematic, which looks the same as that in the question:



Where D1 is a RGL1D from Diotec Semiconductor which is described as a Fast Recovery SMD Rectifier Diode. The package is a DO-213AA Plastic MiniMELF. I.e. different from the glass package shown in the module picture in the question.
Assuming the part number is correct, then D1 isn't a Zener as suspected by the other answer.
With such modules where the manufacturer isn't clear, it is sometimes difficult to know exactly which components are used.

Hm. I can't see what the reasoning would be behind using a rectifier diode here. It doesn't hurt anything, at least.

The package is called MELF¹, and it isn't that rare, though it's an odd choice for this device, where a smaller, more common, and easier-to-use SOD-123 or SOD-323 package would suffice.
If the schematic shown is correct, then the diode seems superfluous. Its only purpose would be to prevent the MOSFET's gate voltage from going too negative, but there's no way I can see that it would go significantly negative at all anyway, even with the terminals connected incorrectly.
I suspect instead that it's a Zener diode, probably rated around 10 to 15 volts (though perhaps as low as 5 V given this MOSFET's low drive voltage), despite being drawn as a standard diode. A Zener here would prevent the MOSFET's gate voltage from going too high, which would be possible if the input rating of 6-28 V were exceeded. The IRLR7843 is rated for a maximum gate voltage of 20 V, so with the voltage divider formed by the two 4.7 kΩ resistors, it wouldn't be possible to exceed that normally, but it doesn't hurt to add the protection anyway. It will also provide some protection against ESD, though the fact that it's separated from the MOSFET by a 100 Ω resistor slightly limits its ability to do so.

¹ Stands for Metal Electrode Leadless Face, though many engineers will tell you it stands for Most End up Lying on the Floor because they tend to roll all over the workbench.
